# Como posso remover divs e depois reinseri-las? (usando apenas javascript)

Tags: javascript

Bom eu tenho a seguinte interface:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é: ao pressionar o botão da esquerda, por exemplo, a página deverá exibir o mês anterior ao atual assim como o número de quadrados relativos ao número de dias daqueles mês (31 em maio, oque está sendo exibido e 30 em abril, oque deveria ser exibido).

A minha ideia foi a seguinte: vou remover todos os quadrados e depois adicioná-los novamente de acordo com o número de dias do mês que deverá ser exibido. Por exemplo, o mês de maio exibe 31 quadrados, ao clicar no botão da esquerda deverá ser exibido o mês de abril, logo deverei remover os 31 quadrados e adicionar 30, relativos ao número de dias de abril.

Só que, eu até consigo remover os quadrados, resultando nisso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando tento adicionar os quadrados novamente recebo uma tela branca:

Antes
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Depois
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Note que o título da página se altera para o nome do arquivo

Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando (javascript):

```
function retornaMes() {
    var mes = document.getElementById("barraLateral");
    var ano = document.getElementById("ano");

    var meses = Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro')

    var mesAntigo = meses.indexOf(mes.innerHTML);
    var mesNovo = meses[mesAntigo - 1];

    if (mesAntigo - 1 == -1){
        mesNovo = meses[11];

        var novoAno = parseInt(ano.innerHTML);
        novoAno = novoAno - 1;

        ano.removeChild(ano.firstChild);
        var novoAno = document.createTextNode(novoAno.toString());
        ano.appendChild(novoAno);
    } 

    mes.removeChild(mes.firstChild);
    var novoMes = document.createTextNode(mesNovo);
    mes.appendChild(novoMes);

    apagaDias(mesAntigo);
    mesAntigo -= 1;
    geraDias(mesAntigo);
}
```

Função responsável por retroceder o mês, chamada no onclick do botão da esquerda

```
function avancaMes() {
    var mes = document.getElementById("barraLateral");

    var meses = Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro')

    var mesAntigo = meses.indexOf(mes.innerHTML);
    var mesNovo = meses[mesAntigo + 1];

    if (mesAntigo+ 1 == 12){
        mesNovo = meses[0];

        var novoAno = parseInt(ano.innerHTML);
        novoAno = novoAno + 1;

        ano.removeChild(ano.firstChild);
        var novoAno = document.createTextNode(novoAno.toString());
        ano.appendChild(novoAno);
    }

    mes.removeChild(mes.firstChild);
    var novoMes = document.createTextNode(mesNovo);
    mes.appendChild(novoMes);

    apagaDias(mesAntigo);
    mesAntigo += 1;
    geraDias(mesAntigo);
}
```

Função responsável por avançar o mês, chamada no onclick do botão da direita

```
function apagaDias(mes) {
    var dias = document.getElementById('quadradoDeData');
    diasPorMes = Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31,30, 31, 30, 31);

    for (var j = 0; j < diasPorMes[mes]; j++) {
        dias = document.getElementById('quadradoDeData').remove();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Função responsável por apagar os quadrados

```
function geraDias(mes) {
    var distanciaX = 0;

    diasPorMes = Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31,30, 31, 30, 31);

    for (i = 1; i <= diasPorMes[mes]; i++) {

        if (i < 10){
            if (i <= 7) {
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * (i -1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -475px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>0"+i+"</div>");
            } else if (i <= 14) {
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * ((i - 7) - 1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -385px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>0"+i+"</div>");
            }
        }else{
            if (i <= 14) {
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * ((i - 7) - 1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -385px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
            }else if (i <= 21){
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * ((i - 14) - 1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -295px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
            }else if (i <= 28) {
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * ((i - 21) - 1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -205px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
            }else{
                distanciaX = 14 + 90 * ((i - 28) - 1);
                document.write("<div id='quadradoDeData' style='margin: -115px 0px 0px "+distanciaX+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Função responsável por repor os quadrados

Resumindo, quero entender porque eu recebo essa tela branca quando tento incluir os quadrados novamente, espero ter esclarecido tudo.

Comment: Seria bom colocar o código completo pra gente tentar reproduzir.

Comment: Se eu não me engano, a `document.write` substitui todo o body da página. Acredito que o melhor seria usar `document.append` nesse caso; ou ainda, criar o elemento no JavaScript e usar `document.createElement` ou `document.appendChild`

Comment: pq não usa o show / hide , com append com jquey?

Comment: tipo:    $('#resposta').html("texto texto"); //CRIA A MENSAGEM
           $('#resposta').show(); mostra mensagem
           $('#resposta').empty(); // zera
           $('#resposta').hide(); // não mostra

Comment: isso seria me php, eu só estou usando javascript

Comment: estou mostrando exemplos em Jquery que é uma biblioteca do javascript. não tem nada a ver com php. é puro front-end

Comment: Entendi, obrigado mesmo assim, consegui resolver alterando o display dos elementos